# Induced topology base

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ be a topological space, $B$ an open base for $X$ and $Y \subseteq X$. Prove that $B_Y = \{U \cap Y: U \in B\}$ is an open base for $Y$ (considering, over $Y$, the subspace topology).

We must show that given an open $A$ relative to the topology of $Y$, we have to show that there is an element of $B_Y$ such that $ A = \cup (U \cap Y) $. Since $ B $ is a base for X, we have that Y can be written as a union of elements of $B$. That is, there is $W \in B$ such that $ Y = \cup W $. Is this demonstration absurd?

Comment: can you please accept the answers that have been useful to you? We see that you asked 17 questions without accepting any answer. This is definitely not polite and you should at least try to follow the rules of this site.

Comment: I don't know, it is not easy to follow what you wrote. It does seem a bit incoherent.

Answer (score 1):

Use the fact that the subspace toplogy $\tau_Y$ is the coarsest one for which the inclusion $i:Y\to X$ is continuous.

If $A$ is open in $Y$ then there is a $V$ open in $X$ such that $i^{-1}(V)=A$. Since $V$ is open in $X$ there is a basis element $B\in \tau_X$   such that $B\subseteq V.$ Then, $i^{-1}(B)=B\cap Y\subseteq A$ and $B\cap Y$ is open (in $Y$) by definition of $\tau_Y.$ It follows that the collection $\{B\cap Y\}_{B\in \tau_X}$ is a base for $\tau_Y.$

Answer (score 0):

Observe that if $B = \{B_i: i \in I \}$ is an open base of $X$ if and only if for any $x$ in open set $G$ there exist $B_i$ in $B$ such that $x \in B_i \subseteq G$.

Now let $A$ be open in $Y$ then  $A = Y \cap G$ where $G$ is open in $X$ and let $x$ be in $A$. Clearly $x \in G$ which implies there is a $B_i$ in $B$ such that $x \in B_i$ and $B_i \subseteq G$. This also implies that $x \in Y \cap B_i$ and clearly $Y \cap B_i \in B_Y$. So we conclude that $B_Y$ is an open base for subspace $Y$.